# SQL Server: SUM() with Row_number() - The sum off all records with row #1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to sum all row_number = 1 but I'd like it to include all other rows but only display the record for row_number 1 but sum all the other rows.

```
SELECT 
    A.TEST, A.BLOCK, A.POLICY, A.SAL_COVERAGE,
    A.YEAR, A.ZIP, A.COVERAGE,
    SUM(A.WP) AS WP,
    SUM(A.WE) AS WE,
    SUM(A.EP) AS EP,
    SUM(A.EE) AS EE
FROM
    (SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ZIP ORDER BY ZIP) AS TEST,
         BLOCK, POLICY, SAL_COVERAGE,
         YEAR, ZIP, COVERAGE,
         SUM(WP) AS WP,
         SUM(WE) AS WE,
         SUM(EP) AS EP,
         SUM(EE) AS EE
     FROM 
         [Reports].[dbo].[DGTESTING]
     GROUP BY
         BLOCK, POLICY, SAL_COVERAGE, YEAR, ZIP, COVERAGE) AS A
WHERE 
    TEST = 1
    AND A.POLICY = 'XXXX'
GROUP BY
    A.TEST, A.BLOCK, A.POLICY, A.SAL_COVERAGE, A.YEAR, A.ZIP, A.COVERAGE
```

The result I am getting is like this:

[image]

I would expect every ZIP to be summed into this record but I am only getting 1. It looks like SQL is doing everything correct but I am missing a way to do what I am intending.

Sample data

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|TEST|BLK|POL |SAL|YEAR|ZIP   |COV  |WP  |WE        |EP    |EE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1   |1  |XXX |1  |2014|96003 |Bod  |-143|-10.888157|-87.59|-6.67
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|32  |6  |XXX |1  |2015|96007 |Bod  |0   |0         |-55.41|-4.21
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Expected data

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|TEST|BLK|POL|SAL|YEAR|ZIP  |COV|WP  |WE        |EP  |EE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1   |  1|XXX|  1|2014|96003|Bod|-143|-10.888157|-143|-10.88
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is more data

[image: More Date]

Comment: can you show some data with expected outcome to go with the code

Comment: One option might be to remove the `SUM` parts from your current subquery and just do a join to another subquery that does nothing other than summing. e.g. `select * from (mysubquery) as a join (select policy, block, sal_coverage, etc, col1 = sum(col1), col2 = sum(col2), etc from mytable group by policy, etc) as b on a.policy = b.policy and a.othercols = b.othercols where a.test = 1 and a.policy = 'xxxx'` or something similar to that.

Comment: Added the data as best I could with text. Hopefully this helps. Ill try your suggestion too.

Comment: Sorry @DavidGomez, I don't understand what logic the query should follow. Please add few more rows to the sample data and expected result in the question. Please show all relevant variations of the data.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov, I have added all records and expected outcome. I am trying to accomplish this in more than one subquery as I am still struggling with this. Thank you for your continued assistance.

Comment: @DavidGomez, I think that the query in my answer would produce your expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query below would return one row for the whole table as in your expected result in the question. It will return one row with the minimum ZIP value.

`SUM(...) OVER()` sums the whole table, for each row. Then we are picking just one row with `rn=1`. Run the inner query first to understand what it does.

```
SELECT 
    A.TEST
    ,A.BLOCK
    ,A.POLICY
    ,A.SAL_COVERAGE
    ,A.YEAR
    ,A.ZIP
    ,A.COVERAGE
    ,A.WP
    ,A.WE
    ,A.EP
    ,A.EE
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ZIP) AS rn
            ,BLOCK
            ,POLICY
            ,SAL_COVERAGE
            ,YEAR
            ,ZIP
            ,COVERAGE
            ,SUM(WP) OVER() AS WP
            ,SUM(WE) OVER() AS WE
            ,SUM(EP) OVER() AS EP
            ,SUM(EE) OVER() AS EE
        FROM [Reports].[dbo].[DGTESTING]
    ) AS A
WHERE 
    rn = 1
;
```

Comment: This is a lot closer to what I need except I have thousands of zips and all need to roll up into rn = 1. The rn = 1 should add up for each different zip. This is helping me get closer though.

Comment: @DavidGomez, OK, you want to partition by Zip, fine. How do you want to order rows with the same Zip? How do you define the "first" row when there are several rows with the same Zip?

Comment: I am trying to use row 1 as the zip to sum all the WP, EP, EE and WE.

Comment: Thank you. This would be true if I only had one zip but I have thousands. This result would need to be for each zip unless I am running the query wrong. Ill keep digging into it. For the purpose of explaining my issues I only gave the resultset for 1 zip which had two different zips included.

Comment: @DavidGomez, if you want to get useful answers you should include in your question such sample data that expected result would illustrate the required logic. If you expect to see more than one row in the result, then show us a good example when it happens. So far, I'm returning back to my statement that I don't understand what kind of logic you need.

Comment: thank you. This forum is new to me and I will work on explaining this better. I appreciate your help.